# Pass std::tuple with variadic template parameter as its elements type to another function as a list of parameters

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates, stdtuple

I have been implementing my version of `std::map` to get more understanding of how things work from the inside. While implementing `std::map::emplace()`, I have ran into a problem.

So, my function signature looks like this:

```
template <typename Key, typename Value>
template <typename ... Args1, typename ... Args2>
std::pair<typename Map<Key, Value>::Iterator, bool> Map<Key, Value>::emplace(
    std::piecewise_construct_t pwc,
    std::tuple<Args1...> first_args,
    std::tuple<Args2...> second_args);
```

Before actual emplacing, I do need to construct the key from `first_args` in order to compare keys in the tree. I have tried a few things, but cannot figure out the correct way to do this. As I understand, it should look something like this:

```
Key k(std::get<sizeof...(Args1)>(std::forward<Args1>(first_args));
```

Problem is that, for each element of the tuple, `std::get()` should receive a different number as its template parameter (so that the correct element of the tuple would be passed in the correct place).

I've seen people solve this problem by having size as template parameter and passing `std::index_sequence` as one of parameters, but `std::map::emplace()` does not have any of this approach, so there should be a way to do implement emplacing without this.

Thank you in advance. Any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: Your function signature differs from that of `std::map` which is why "std::map::emplace() does not have any of this approach". Have a look at [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace). If you absolutely must use a tuple then you might be able to use [`std::make_from_tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/make_from_tuple). It's a C++17 library feature but it can easily be implemented in C++14 using `std::index_sequence`.

Comment: `std::map::emplace` offloads the work to the [constructor of `std::pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair).

Comment: Did you check the page I linked? `std::pair` has a constructor that accepts `std::piecewise_construct_t, std::tuple<Args1...> first_args, std::tuple<Args2...> second_args` which will do the work for you.

Comment: @Kerndog73 Oh so we can just forward the parameters in case of std::piecewise_construct to std::pair constructor. Same as in other cases.
Thank you.

The one thing that I did not understand that is that we have to have the key  before emplacing, in order to traverse the tree and find, where to emplace the element. In case when no reference to the key is provided, how will we do comparasion between the key and the keys of the map elements without constructing it before creating the actual node?

Comment: Construct the pair from the arguments: `std::pair<Key, Value> pair(std::forward<Args>(args)...)` (allowing `std::pair` to deal with all the tricky details). Use `pair.first` to figure out where you need to put it. Then `std::move` it to where it needs to be.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you read the [cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) to learn about the details of `std::map`.

Comment: @Kerndog73 but then we lose the whole idea of emplace? The described way is just the same as insert, except that we create the pair any way the user provided. From std::map::emplace() description: careful use of emplace allows the new element to be constructed while avoiding unnecessary copy or move operations. In case we create the whole node first, we will have "unnecessary move operations".

Comment: I’m not familiar with the details but I’m pretty sure `std::map` is implemented with some kind of tree. The tree nodes are dynamically allocated so you can construct the pair directly in the node when you allocate it. Then you just have to fiddle around with pointers to insert the node into the tree. The pair will be constructed directly into the node so there aren’t any extra copies or moves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've seen people solve this problem by having size as template parameter and passing std::index_sequence as one of parameters, but std::map::emplace() does not have any of this approach, so there should be a way to do implement emplacing without this.

It's true that `std::map::emplace()` do not receive a `std::index_sequence`, but I don't know if, internally, create a `std::index_sequence` and call an helper function to correctly manage the tuple.

In other words, you can write something as follows

```
Key k { make_object_from_tuple<Key>(first_arg, std::index_sequence_for<Args1...>{}) };
```

and inside `make_object_from_tuple()` you can use the `std::index_sequence` to extract element from tuple and construct the `Key` object.

In other words: as suggested from Kerndog73, you can copy the `std::make_from_tuple_impl()` implementation in [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/make_from_tuple).

If you don't want develop a new function, you can use the piecewise contructor from `std::pair`.

Nothing force you to construct a `std::pair<Key, Value>`: if you want construct first a `Key` and, only if necessary, next the `Value`, you can construct before a `std::pair<Key, int>` and after (in the case) a `std::pair<Value, int>`.

I mean... you can create the `Key` without the `Value`

```
std::tuple<int> ti{0};

Key k { std::pair<Key, int>{std::piecewise_construct_t, first_args, ti).first };
```

and after, only if you need it, the `Value`

```
Value v { std::pair<Value, int>{std::piecewise_construct_t, second_args, ti).first };
```

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for! Now, that, I was able to create the Key object from the tuple, the rest is trivial.

It works, thanks a lot!